# Подскажите, откуда при мобильной адаптации происходит прокрутка?

Tags: html, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

http://f0186535.xsph.ru/two/two.html

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mouse+Memoirs');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  background: url(img/Wielokąt.png) no-repeat top;
}

.plate {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  width: 64%;
  height: 627px;
  line-height: 627px;
  background: url(img/Background.png) no-repeat;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: 1.7%;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu>.soup {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 25px/27px 'Mouse Memoirs', sans-serif;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  padding: 0.4em 1.08em 0.4em 1.08em;
  background: #131313;
}

.items {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 14px/30px 'Mouse Memoirs', sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  padding: 0.6em 1.08em 0.6em 1.08em;
  background: #ee7b00;
}

.borderright {
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f3ef;
}

.items:hover {
  background: #e9ac54;
}

.menu>.soup>img {
  width: 26px;
  height: 27px;
}

.menu>.items>img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
}

.soup-recipes {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 31px;
  font: 24px/30px 'Mouse Memoirs', sans-serif;
  color: #131313;
  margin-top: 62%;
  margin-left: -50%;
}

.prostokat {
  width: 31px;
  height: 33px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 33px;
  background: #ee7b00;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
}

.triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 12px solid transparent;
  border-left: 19px solid white;
  border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.triangle-up {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 12px solid transparent;
  border-left: 19px solid #ee7b00;
  border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 7px;
}

.suprecipes {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.recipes {
  margin-top: 2.6%;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 111px;
  background: #eabc74;
  line-height: 111px;
}

.recipes-second-row {
  margin-top: 17px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.recipes-center-color {
  background: #f1962e;
}

.recipes-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 62%;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  background: #ee7b00;
}

.recipes-text-caption {
  font: 18px/30px 'Mouse Memoirs', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 0.7em;
  color: #131313;
}

.recipes-text-row-two {
  font: 12px/12px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 12px;
  margin-left: 2.8em;
  display: block;
}

.recipes-text-caption-row-two {
  font: 18px/30px 'Mouse Memoirs', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  margin-left: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  color: #131313;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.section-letters {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  height: 128px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.a-z {
  width: 16.6%;
  line-height: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.from-a-z {
  width: 27%;
  line-height: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.letters {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 56.4%;
  height: 128px;
}

.letter {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0.7em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 20px 'Mouse Memoirs', sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.letter-right {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.letter:hover {
  background: #eabc74;
}

.a-z>span {
  display: inline-block;
  font: 40px 'Mouse Memoirs', sans-serif;
}

.listed {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 15px;
  font: 13px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.listed-row-two {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5em;
}

.listed-row-one {
  display: inline-block;
}

.bottom-part {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 114px;
  background: #eabc74;
}

.bottom-part-content {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.cap {
  width: 11%;
  height: 114px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ee7b00;
}

.prescription {
  width: 35%;
  height: 114px;
  background: #f1debf;
}

.prescriptionone {
  margin-left: 5.6%;
  font: 18px/40px 'Mouse Memoirs', sans-serif;
}

.prescriptiontwo {
  margin-left: 5.6%;
  font: 12px/18px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.try-out {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 42.5%;
  height: 137.7%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  background: #eaa141;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.try-out-text {
  font: 13px/20px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  width: 24.6%;
  height: 74%;
  background: #eaa141;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.gallery-contact {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 11.5%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  background: #f6ce90;
}

.gallery-contact-enter {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery>p {
  width: 78%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
  font: 17px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.gallery>div {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: white;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.basement {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 100px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-basement {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.basement-container-menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.basement-menu {
  font: 12px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.publication {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.publication-text {
  font: 12px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .main {
    max-width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    background: url(img/Wielokątmobile.png) no-repeat top;
  }
  .plate {
    background: #eabc74;
    height: 50%;
    width: 60%;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu {
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .borderright {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f3ef;
  }
  .items {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .soup-recipes {
    display: none;
  }
  .recipes {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .recipes-second-row {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .suprecipes {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .section-letters {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
  }
  .a-z {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ee7b00;
  }
  .from-a-z {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ee7b00;
  }
  .letters {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .recipes-text-row-two {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .row-one {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .row-two {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .letter-mobile {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .letter {
    font: 16px 'Mouse Memoirs', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 5%;
  }
  .listed {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .listed-row-two {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .bottom-part {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .bottom-part-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .cap {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .prescription {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .try-out {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: white;
  }
  .try-out-text {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
  }
  .gallery-contact {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .basement {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .content-basement {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: none;
  }
  .basement-container-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .basement-menu {
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #6e6e6e;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .publication {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .publication-text {
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #6e6e6e;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>soup</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mouse+Memoirs" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <article class="plate">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="" class="soup">
          <img src="img/food.png">
          <span>Soup</span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="items borderright">
          <span>Home</span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="items borderright">
          <span>Recipies</span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="items borderright">
          <span>Blog</span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="items borderright">
          <span>Gallery</span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="items">
          <span>Contact</span>
          <img src="img/Kształt 3.png">
          <img src="img/Kształt 2.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="soup-recipes">
        <div class="prostokat">
          <div class="triangle"></div>
          <div class="triangle-up"></div>
        </div>
        <span>Soup recipes</span>
      </div>
    </article>
    <section class="suprecipes">
      <div class="recipes">
        <p class="recipes-text">
          <span class="recipes-text-caption">Nettle soup</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="recipes recipes-center-color">
        <p class="recipes-text">
          <span class="recipes-text-caption">Spicy lentil soup</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="recipes">
        <p class="recipes-text">
          <span class="recipes-text-caption">Rich tomato soup</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="recipes recipes-second-row">
        <p class="recipes-text-caption-row-two">Special Diets</p>
        <span class="recipes-text-row-two">Low-salt, egg-free, dairy-free and gluten-free are just some of the options.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="recipes recipes-second-row recipes-center-color">
        <p class="recipes-text-caption-row-two">Vegetarian</p>
        <span class="recipes-text-row-two">Tempting meat-free meals and other vegetarian fare.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="recipes recipes-second-row">
        <p class="recipes-text-caption-row-two">Need Inspiration?</p>
        <span class="recipes-text-row-two">Use our refined recipe search to help you find the dish that suits you</span>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section-letters">
      <div class="a-z">
        <span>A-Z of recipes</span>
      </div>
      <div class="from-a-z">
        <div class="listed">
          <p class="listed-row-one">Our recipes are listed from A to Z.</p>
          <p class="listed-row-two">Have a browse...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="letters">
        <div class="row-one">
          <a href="" class="letter letter-right">a</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">b</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">c</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">d</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">e</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">f</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">g</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">h</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">i</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">j</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">k</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">l</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">m</a>
        </div>
        <div class="row-two">
          <a href="" class="letter letter-mobile">n</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">o</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">p</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">q</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">r</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">s</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">t</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">u</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">v</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">w</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">x</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">y</a>
          <a href="" class="letter">z</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="bottom-part">
      <div class="bottom-part-content">
        <div class="cap">
          <img src="img/cap.png">
        </div>
        <div class="prescription">
          <p class="prescriptionone">Soup recipes</p>
          <p class="prescriptiontwo">Warming soup recipes to nourish the soul, and help use up all those extra vegetables lurking in your fridge crisper.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="try-out">
          <p class="try-out-text">Try something different for vegetarians with Moroccan chickpea soup</p>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-contact">
          <div class="gallery-contact-enter">
            <div class="gallery">
              <p>Gallery</p>
              <div><img src="img/triangl.png"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
              <p>Contact</p>
              <div><img src="img/airplane.png"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="basement">
      <div class="content-basement">
        <div class="basement-container-menu">
          <a href="" class="basement-menu">Home</a>
          <a href="" class="basement-menu">Recipies</a>
          <a href="" class="basement-menu">Blog</a>
          <a href="" class="basement-menu">Gallery</a>
          <a href="" class="basement-menu">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="publication">
          <p class="publication-text">Design by Webvilla.pl 2013</p>
        </div>
      </div>


    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `max-width` у `.main` в медийных запросах меньше

Comment: точно также. Откуда она вообще появляется